# JQuery Calculator not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a tile calculator but can't seem to get the following code to work:

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function caculateForm() {
        var length = document.getElementById('length').value;
        var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
        var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
        var compute = (length * width) / (size / 100);
        var total = compute * 100;
        var allowance = (compute * 100) * .10;
        allowance = Math.floor(total) + Math.floor(allowance + 1);
        document.getElementById('total').value = Math.floor(total);
        document.getElementById('allowance').value = allowance;
    }
});


$(document).ready(
    function clearFileInput(id) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        elem.parentNode.innerHTML = elem.parentNode.innerHTML;
    }
});
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8ehW/)

Comment: 2 times `}})'` in fiddle?? and `document.ready(function clearFileInput(id){`??

Comment: you got the `$(document).ready` declaration wrong

Comment: Try to click on the JSHint button in your fiddle to discover typos, then remove all JS inline code to create JQUery click events instead, then use JQuery selector instead of direct javascript, then ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSfiddle, remove your `$(document).ready()`s :

```
function caculateForm() {
    var length = document.getElementById('length').value;
    var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
    var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
    var compute = (length * width) / (size / 100);
    var total = compute * 100;
    var allowance = (compute * 100) * .10;
    allowance = Math.floor(total) + Math.floor(allowance + 1);
    document.getElementById('total').value = Math.floor(total);
   document.getElementById('allowance').value = allowance;
}

function clearFileInput(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.parentNode.innerHTML = elem.parentNode.innerHTML;
}
```

And select "No wrap - in head" option .. then it should work

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8ehW/3/

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle with jQuery selectors.

Clearing function needed to be redone, so changed it to

```
function clearFileInput() {
    var elements = $("input[type=text], select");

    elements.each(function(key, elem) {
        elem.parentNode.innerHTML = elem.parentNode.innerHTML;
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jansav/b9LN5/